Why I my Azure Container App cant access ACR
Hi guys I have an issue.
I pushed my docker image to ACR and when I tried to configure it in Container app to create a container to deploy it in Cotainer Apps Env..It throw me an error saying that ‘Cant access ACR (repo name) because admin credentials on ACR are disabled..
So I solved that issue by Enabling Admin privileges on Access keys tabs.
But its not the best practice since it’s encouraged to use managed identity access another service without exposing username and passwords.
Any Idea how to solve this
I tried creating User managed identity with ACRpull role but to assign that identity in container app it need to created first..Any other leads.

You can create a container with quick start image, Assign the roles after container apps creation and then create a new revision for container apps with ACR image.
Follow the following steps to use Managed identity:

To create container apps with quick start image scroll up and you will find check box.




Open deployed Container app, enable system assigned identity/ add user assigned identity.



Assign Role to the system assigned identity in ACR.



Open container app> Go to containers blade> Click on Edit and Deploy> Select the container and click on edit, Add all the required details and save


OUTPUT:
I am using default caddy image here.

